# AFM cantilevers driven below resonance?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, resonance, metrology

Is there a physical reason why AFM cantilevers are driven below their resonance frequencies?

In all of the AFMs I have used, once you measure the resonance frequency of the cantilever, it is set up to be driven slightly below this frequency for measurement. Is this a convention? Does driving at resonance cause damage? If not, then why is the cantilever not also driven above resonance? I seem to recall an engineer telling me that driving below resonance improves the resolution and referenced a paper - but I can't find this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resonance curve is a Lorentzian shape (which looks similar to a Gaussian bell-shaped curve).  When the slope of the Lorentzian is at a maximum (i.e. slightly off resonance), the driven system will be most sensitive to changes in the resonant frequency.  In the linked article, notice that the amplitude $A_0$ is marked on the steep part of the Lorentzian, which makes $A_+$ and $A_-$ very different from $A_0$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-contact_atomic_force_microscopy#Amplitude_modulation

Comment: But why below resonance and not above? Also, why is the resonance Gaussian? Resonances are so often Lorentzian...

Comment: I don't know why below resonance.  Maybe the idea is to try to avoid going to large amplitude as you near the surface, risking a crashed tip.

Comment: Yes, it's probably Lorentzian.  Looking at the driven damped harmonic oscillator, that looks more appropriate.